# How to pre process my data according to their own condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

Recently I thought to change the viewing of my data from segregating the total value into smaller sources of KPI

I would like to transform my data like so to

```
>>df.head(20)
Year    Month   Segment Region  KPI        Value Type   Value
0   2020    12  Clients India   Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 3665558
1   2020    12  Clients India   Lv2_Visitors    Actuals 2689569
2   2020    12  Clients India   Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 1300571
3   2020    12  Clients India   Lv4_Visitors    Actuals 717608
4   2020    12  Clients India   Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 706677
5   2020    12  Clients India   Lv5_Visitors    Actuals 255723
6   2020    12  Clients India   Lv4_Visitors    Actuals 180125
7   2020    12  Clients India   Lv5_Visitors    Actuals 74768
8   2021    12  Clients India   Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 3543797
9   2021    12  Clients India   Lv2_Visitors    Actuals 2199420
10  2021    12  Clients India   Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 1105675
11  2021    12  Clients India   Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 677096
12  2021    12  Clients India   Lv4_Visitors    Actuals 632424
13  2021    12  Clients India   Lv5_Visitors    Actuals 216178
14  2021    12  Clients India   Lv4_Visitors    Actuals 180821
15  2021    12  Clients India   Lv5_Visitors    Actuals 69345
16  2022    12  Clients India   Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 3223690
17  2022    12  Clients India   Lv2_Visitors    Actuals 2106583
18  2022    12  Clients India   Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 1725522
19  2022    12  Clients India   Lv4_Visitors    Actuals 748273
20  2022    12  Clients Uddepy  Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 629047
21  2022    12  Clients Uddepy  Lv2_Visitors    Actuals 378447
22  2022    12  Clients Uddepy  Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 371666
23  2022    12  Clients Dehradun    Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 241370
24  2022    12  Clients Ujjain  Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 178976
25  2022    12  Clients Dehradun    Lv2_Visitors    Actuals 149024
26  2022    12  Clients Indore  Lv1_Visitors    Actuals 119475
27  2022    12  Clients Uddepy  Lv4_Visitors    Actuals 118950
28  2022    12  Clients Dehradun    Lv3_Visitors    Actuals 118570
29  2022    12  Clients Ujjain  Lv2_Visitors    Actuals 112987
```

to this

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AsdN.png): [image]

The numbers are not accurate

Comment: Have you considered using https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html